# Generate WS-Security Security Context Token in Java

Tags: java, ws-security

A web service provider has implemented WS-Security in .net to secure its web service. I'm confused how to I generate security context token in java as per WS-Security standard?

I checkout Apache Rampart policies but found that none of the policy's request has security context token node. Not getting a head start for it.

Could someone please help ?

Below is the soap header sample.

```
<s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand = "1">url</a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:044c513b-5c79-4d32-8ef7-e5be7d32dd9a</a:MessageID>
    <a:ReplyTo>
        <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand = "1">service provider url</a:To>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand = "1" xmlns:o = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <u:Timestamp u:Id = "_0">
            <u:Created>2016-01-20T17:01:54.480Z</u:Created>
            <u:Expires>2016-01-20T17:06:54.480Z</u:Expires>
        </u:Timestamp>
        <c:SecurityContextToken u:Id = "uuid-58ee82ff-1b76-4228-8c86-1d99dee0122e-5" xmlns:c = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc">
            <c:Identifier>urn:uuid:b2cb2469-3b5a-49a9-9ddf-f1441f194012</c:Identifier>
        </c:SecurityContextToken>
        <Signature xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignedInfo>
                <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm = "http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                <SignatureMethod Algorithm = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#hmac-sha1"/>
                <Reference URI = "#_0">
                    <Transforms>
                        <Transform Algorithm = "http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    </Transforms>
                    <DigestMethod Algorithm = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                    <DigestValue>6pHwg2hMn0bYulROisZFtKXHi+c=</DigestValue>
                </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue>TJIjNDK87fY2oZ3lD6iTFzaOCKU=</SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo>
                <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                    <o:Reference ValueType = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct" URI = "#uuid-58ee82ff-1b76-4228-8c86-1d99dee0122e-5"/>
                </o:SecurityTokenReference>
            </KeyInfo>
        </Signature>
    </o:Security>
</s:Header>
```

Comment: When asking a question, try to be as specific as possible. Since your question is way too broad, and does not show the attempts you already made, most users will glance oveer this question and not answer it, even if they know it.

Comment: @joe did you find a way to do it. I'm stuck up in the same way